# Autocomplete on textfield with focusout not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

I am trying to achieve the following with the below code

When a user types id in "Id" text field the autocomplete should be called and upon selection of any id's in the drop down list as a result of the autocomplete .Then an ajax call should be made to pull the location in to an another select field

```
<input type="text" id="Id" name="Id0" class="IdClass" maxlength="20" onkeydown="autoCompleteIdSearch(this)"/></td>
```

Above is how I call the function from a jsp page

```
function autoCompleteIdSearch(input)
{
    var rowid = input.name.substring(8);


    $('[name="Id'+rowid+'"]').autocompleteIdNum(
              { minLength: 1 },
              {source: 'getAllIdNum'},
              {select: function (event, ui){

                  $('[name="Id'+rowid+'"]').live('focusout', function() {
                        rowid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id').replace("Idrow", "");
                getSchoolLocations(rowid,ui.item.value,"");
                    });
              }}
             );
}
```

But the locations field loaded with values only when i click out the Id text field area. Please correct me if i had any wrong

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding another piece of code to handle the event and below wascode and it worked

```
$('#Id').live("paste", function(e) {
    rowid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id').replace("IdClass", "");
   getSchoolLocations(rowid,e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text'),"");
});
```